# including Zeros counts categories with pandas value_counts()

Tags: pandas

What i want is including zero counts categories while generating frequencies for categorical variables

```
example:

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['a', 'c', 'a', 'e'],
    'col2': ['x', 'y', 'y', 'z'],
})

col1   col2 
a       x
c       y
a       y
e       z
```

what I want is to generate a frequency table with counts and percentages including zero counts categories

results

```
  Counts   Cercentage
a  2          50.0%
b  0          0.0%
c  1          25.0%
d  0          0.0%
e  1          25.0%
```

What I have done is generating the frequency table with counts and percentages, but I need to include also the zero counts categories like b and d as illustrated above.

Here's what I have tried:

```
pd.concat([df.col1.value_counts(dropna=False),
           df.col1.value_counts(normalize=True,
                                dropna=False).mul(100).round(1).astype(str) + '%'],
          axis=1,
          keys=('Counts','Percentage'))
```

any help please

Comment: Hello there, could you please try to use Code blocks so your tables look cleaner, and give a clear example of what you try to do ? I can't understand the question...

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer use of Series.reindex with a list of all categories and if not match replace to 0

```
  categories = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
  pd.concat([df.col1.value_counts().reindex(categories[::-1], fill_value=0),        df.col1.value_counts(normalize=True).reindex(categories[::-1], fill_value=0).mul(100).round(1).astype(str) + '%'],axis=1, keys=('Counts','Percentage'))
```

This worked for me

Comment: Welcome to DS SE! If you answered your own question, would you please mark it as such? Click the checkmark under the vote buttons on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use Pandas [Categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#categorical). Categorical types define all the values the variables might take on, even if none of those values are observed in the data.

```
abcde_categorical = pd.CategoricalDtype(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ordered=True)
xyz_categorical = pd.CategoricalDtype(['x', 'y', 'z'], ordered=True)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': pd.Categorical(['a', 'c', 'a', 'e'], dtype=abcde_categorical),
    'col2': pd.Categorical(['x', 'y', 'y', 'z'], dtype=xyz_categorical),
})

  col1 col2
0    a    x
1    c    y
2    a    y
3    e    z
```

Then, the frequency table can be computed as follows:

```
pd.concat([
        df.col1.value_counts(sort=False),
        df.col1.value_counts(sort=False, normalize=True),
    ],
    axis=1
)
```

Sadly, [DataFrame.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) doesn't [yet](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44001) as of Pandas 2.1.1 respect categoricals the way [Series.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) does. You'd think this would work:

```
pd.concat([
        df.value_counts(sort=False),
        df.value_counts(sort=False, normalize=True),
    ],
    axis=1
)
```

...but you'd get:

```
           count  proportion
col1 col2
a    x         1        0.25
     y         1        0.25
c    y         1        0.25
e    z         1        0.25
```

The [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) trick is one way to fix that:

```
index_values = [
    (col1, col2)
    for col1 in abcde_categorical.categories
        for col2 in xyz_categorical.categories
]

pd.concat([
        df.value_counts(sort=False).reindex(index_values, fill_value=0),
        df.value_counts(sort=False, normalize=True).reindex(index_values, fill_value=0),
    ],
    axis=1
)
```

Alternatively, [DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html) does respect categoricals. The argument `observed=False` is saying, "I want the zeros!"

```
df_freq = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(["col1", "col2"], observed=False).size(), columns=['count'])
df_freq['proportion'] = df_freq['count'] / sum(df_freq['count'])
```

Maybe there's a nicer way to make groupby compute proportions, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand the question, but if I only consider the title "including empty categories with pandas value_counts()" here's the way to do it :

```
df['COLUMN'].value_counts(dropna=False)
```

Comment: sorry maybe that was not well state but i want is to include zero counts

Answer (score 0):

didn't read this whole thing - but i stumbled upon this same question. you can just convert the column you're running value_counts() on to a string and that will include nans and 0s.